# Не работает gulp в командной строке,ругается на отсутствие модуля gulp-sass

Tags: node.js, gulp

Установил Node.js и приступил к установке gulp(скопировал нужные файлы)
Выполнил следующие команды в командной строке:

```
npm -v
npm -i
npm i
npm i npm-check-updates -g
ncu -u

All dependencies match the latest package versions :)
```

В итоге при запуске `gulp`

```
C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink>gulp
module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-sass'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\gulpfile.js:4:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

Пытался устранить проблему

```
C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink>npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
npm WARN opencart-project@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm\node_modules\dezalgo
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm\node_modules\dezalgo' -> 'C:\Open\OSPanel\domains\Compulink\node_modules\npm\node_modules\.dezalgo.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-11T14_14_39_229Z-debug.log
```

Но проблема так и не решилась

**UPD**
Одна из основных ошибок как я понял,это отсутствии файла  `\node_modules\npm\node_modules\dezalgo` .

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install -savedev gulp-sass
```

А вообще:

```
man npm
```

Comment: Не помогает,в 1-ом случае пишет что нету файла dezalgo.А во 2-ом случае с man npm пишет что нет такой команды.

Answer (score -1):

Проблема решилась с помощью данной последовательности команд
Перед всем этим удалил

```
   npm clean cache
```

а затем установка по новой

```
1)npm -v
2)npm i npm check updates g
3)npm i npm check updates
4)npm i -g gulp
5)npm install gulp-sass --save-dev
```

`dezalgo` не теряется и не удаляется,и установка модуля `gulp-sass` прошла без ошибок